# Error when running a basic Hadoop code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am running a hadoop code that has a partitioner class inside the job. But, when I run the command

```
hadoop jar Sort.jar SecondarySort inputdir outputdir
```

I am getting a runtime error that says

```
class KeyPartitioner not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner.
```

I have ensured that the KeyPartitioner class has extended the Partitioner class, but why am I getting this error?

Here is the driver code:

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), SecondarySort.class);
    conf.setJobName(SecondarySort.class.getName());

    conf.setJarByClass(SecondarySort.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(StockKey.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setPartitionerClass((Class<? extends Partitioner<StockKey, DoubleWritable>>) KeyPartitioner.class);

    conf.setMapperClass((Class<? extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, StockKey, DoubleWritable>>) StockMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass((Class<? extends Reducer<StockKey, DoubleWritable, Text, Text>>) StockReducer.class);
```

and here is the code of the partitioner class:

```
public class KeyPartitioner extends Partitioner<StockKey, Text> {

@Override
public int getPartition(StockKey arg0, Text arg1, int arg2) {

    int partition = arg0.name.hashCode() % arg2;

    return partition;
}
}
```

Comment: Paste the code - without the code it would be a wild guess only.

Comment: Show us the import list.

Comment: Thanks. The import statements are changed accordingly to @Tudor 's answer below. A new error pops up now saying -> output directory not set in JobConf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there are two partitioners in hadoop:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner
```

Make sure your `KeyPartitioner` class implements the second interface, not the first abstract class.

**Edit**: You have to set the input and output folders:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed the import statements correctly. A new error comes now:    -> output directory not set in JobConf.

Comment: In the new [`Hadoop - The Definitive Guide`](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do) there is an entire section on the new API and the examples in the book are also based on the new API. Would suggest to get the book.